How to use RGB backlight or Backlit keyboard in Ubuntu 24.04
How to use backlight of keyboard in Ubuntu 24.04? I am using Dell g16 7630, with an Nvidia graphics card.
I tried brightnessctl but no luck. Instead I got this error: Device 'tpacpi::kbd_backlight' not found
Result of brightnessctl --list :
Available devices:

Device 'nvidia_wmi_ec_backlight' of class 'backlight':
    Current brightness: 64 (25%)
    Max brightness: 255

Device 'input11::scrolllock' of class 'leds':
    Current brightness: 0 (0%)
    Max brightness: 1

Device 'platform::mute' of class 'leds':
    Current brightness: 0 (0%)
    Max brightness: 1

Device 'phy0-led' of class 'leds':
    Current brightness: 1 (100%)
    Max brightness: 1

Device 'input2::numlock' of class 'leds':
    Current brightness: 0 (0%)
    Max brightness: 1

Device 'input2::capslock' of class 'leds':
    Current brightness: 0 (0%)
    Max brightness: 1

Device 'input2::scrolllock' of class 'leds':
    Current brightness: 0 (0%)
    Max brightness: 1

Device 'input11::capslock' of class 'leds':
    Current brightness: 0 (0%)
    Max brightness: 1

Device 'input11::numlock' of class 'leds':
    Current brightness: 0 (0%)
    Max brightness: 1

Device 'alienware::global_brightness' of class 'leds':
    Current brightness: 15 (100%)
    Max brightness: 15

Device 'dell::kbd_backlight' of class 'leds':
    Current brightness: 1 (50%)
    Max brightness: 2

Device 'platform::micmute' of class 'leds':
    Current brightness: 0 (0%)
    Max brightness: 1

